# Cascading delete may cause cycles

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Request and a table named LoadingBase. A "request" has a loading place and an unloading place. Both these infos are saved in LoadingBase.

So for example:

Request #123 ...

- reference the LoadingBase #567 for the loading info
- reference the LoadingBase #568 for the unloading info

So I have Foreign Key Relationships:

- FK_Requests_LoadingBases_Loading_ID (Delete rule: no action)
- FK_Requests_LoadingBases_Unloading_ID (Delete rule: no action)

Now I would like to set CASCADING DELETE in place.

When I set it for the first FK (Delete rule: cascade) and save it, the save is successful.

When I try for the second FK I got the following error:

'LoadingBases' table saved successfully
'Requests' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Requests_LoadingBases_Loading_ID'.
**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Requests_LoadingBases_Loading_ID' on table 'Requests' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.** Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Does someone have an idea how can I perform a cascade delete on this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. In my opinion cascade delete is a horrible thing anyway and should generally not be used.  Write a delete procedure instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'write a delete procedure'. Do you mean a stored procedure? I'm using SQL EXPRESS. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes I mean a stored procedure.